# Problems with Paths on brew doctor

Tags: git, path, local, homebrew, bin

I have tried as much as I can, I'm new to this whole environment but everything I seem to do isn't fixing the problem.

If I uninstall git with `brew uninstall git`and run `brew doctor` everything is fine. If I install git with `brew install git` then I get this error:

> Warning: /usr/bin occurs before /usr/local/bin This means that
>   system-provided programs will be used instead of those provided by
>   Homebrew. The following tools exist at both paths:
>
> ```
> git
> git-cvsserver
> git-receive-pack
> git-shell
> git-upload-archive
> git-upload-pack
> ```
>
> Consider setting your PATH so that /usr/local/bin occurs before
>   /usr/bin. Here is a one-liner:
>       echo export PATH='/usr/local/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bash_profile`

I've copied that code and pasted it into the terminal but it didn't work. I've also looked online and checked Stackoverflow, everytime I use the code or do something else it just runs normally and then still throws this error, I've tried restarting the computer and just iTerm itself but I still get this error.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

This is what I get from `which git`

```
/usr/bin/git
```

This is what I get from typing `echo $PATH`

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/alexandermcintosh/.rvm/bin
```

Comment: Can you paste the output of `which git`?

Comment: Probably a `PATH` variable ordering problem. In addition to the output of `which git`, can you also please add the output of `echo $PATH`?

Comment: This is what I get from `which git` - `/usr/bin/git`.

This is what I get from typing `echo $PATH` - 

`/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/alexandermcintosh/.rvm/bin`